# Custom Plugin activation error in Multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, errors, activation

I have created one custom plugin but when i try to Network Active in multisite its generate error like below

[image]

But when i install plugin from individual admin its successfully activated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the custom plugin operate with a set of capabilities (permissions) for the user that require it to be a Super Admin?  Keep in mind that if you're using `current_user_can()` or something to check capabilities (such as on loading a file), there are certain "admin" capabilities from single WordPress that are only available to a Super Admin in multisite.  - Not enough info from what you posted to know if that's it, but it's something to check into.

Comment: @butlerblog No there are no any capabilities conditions in plugin

Comment: I mean the redirect after activation is wrong, normally the parameter `activate=true` is only short active and the rewrite back to the wp-admin page. Maybe you have an problem in the plugin about this topic.

Comment: But there are no redirect set in `register_activation_hook` after activated